# Apache Lucene error while using Elasticsearch dependency

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch

I am trying to work with Elasticsearch using Spring boot. When I added the maven dependency:

```xml
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.elasticsearch/elasticsearch -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
    <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
    <version>7.5.1</version>
</dependency>
```

and build the project it is throwing me an error saying:

> Cannot resolve org.apache.lucene:lucene-sandbox:8.3.0

I tried to look into this issue, but since I am new to Elasticsearch didn't find anything meaningful.

What should be correct and potential way to avoid using `apache.lucene`?

Comment: Is this useful? https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/17803

Comment: No, it said --- Could not find artifact org.apache.lucene:lucene-sandbox:jar:8.3.0 in Lucene snapshots (https://download.elasticsearch.org/lucenesnapshots/f0aa4fc)

Comment: at https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/lucene/lucene-sandbox/8.3.0/lucene-sandbox-8.3.0.jar the missing jar is available, what tells me, that your maven cannot pull the dependency. are you using an ide with mvn integration? is the error the same on the shell? do you have a proxy like nexus or jfrog in between? caching? try `dependency:purge-local-repository` to purge and re-download the project dependencies.

Comment: Hey, I am using IntellIJ and in the shell it is not throwing any such error. I am not using any proxy.

Comment: Thank you @ibexit I added this library and it worked for me.